# Combination of rules with Regex

Tags: android, regex

In an android project, im trying to validate a password that the user inputs, and it must follow some rules

The rules are:
it must have 7 characters and 3 of the following conditions

**

> -One lowercase character
>
> -One uppercase character
>
> -One number
>
> -One special character

**

for example:

> asd123!!!
>
> PPPppp000
>
> TTT999###

i was trying with this regex

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{7,}+$
```

but this enforces all rules at same time.

Comment: and what do you need regex for? if you want to validate your input just iterate over all characters and check your criteria

Comment: "three of the following four conditions" is going to be annoying : you will have to use an alternation to describe the possible combinations

Comment: @pskink, its not a actual need, i was just wondering if it was possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach is wrong here. The regex you created looks like a monster from under the bed, and is highly illegible even for someone regex-literate.

Why not split it into 4 (or as much as there are rules) regexes and check against whether 3 of them return a match? Not only will you make your regexes cleaner, but you will be able to add more rules if need be without changing whole regex.

You can also use inbuilt methods for checking (if applicable under Android development kit).

Some pseudocode would look like this:

```
result1 = Regex.IsMatch(password, rule1regex)
result2 = Regex.IsMatch(password, rule2regex)
...
resultN = Regex.IsMatch(password, rule3regex)

if(three_out_of_four_rules_apply)
    password_valid = true
```

You can also apply method suggested in comments by @pskink and iterate over each character of a password and set the output accordingly.

Comment: Just a sidenote - the question is not bad. It's legitimate question that deserves being kept, and the answer @Aaron gave is also good (have my upvote, Aaron :)). This just simply is overkill (albeit possible) in pure regex.

Answer (score 2):

Without going into the details of your lookaheads (which seem correct), here's how you would need to implement "three out of four criteria" in pure regex :

```
(?=.*A)(?=.*B)(?=.*C)|(?=.*A)(?=.*B)(?=.*D)|(?=.*A)(?=.*C)(?=.*D)|(?=.*B)(?=.*C)(?=.*D)
```

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/qzLx82/3).

Factorizing doesn't really make it better :

```
(?=.*A)(?:(?=.*B)(?=.*(?:C|D))|(?=.*C)(?=.*D))|(?=.*B)(?=.*C)(?=.*D)
```

I obviously recommend using a higher level language to implement these sorts of constraints.

Comment: I accepted @Asunez answer cause it made more sense, but thanks for your help

Comment: @Ric sure, I'm relieved you're not actually using this code ;)